# Eliminar valores duplicados de una variable en php

Tags: php

En una varibale tengo los valores repetidos

```
$variable= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3";
```

existe alguna funcionalidad de php que permita eliminar los valores repetidos=

hice la prueba con `array_unique($variable);`
pero me genera un errror al realizar la prueba

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Hola buenos días, convierte el string a array para que así lo puedas trabajar  ya que le estas pasando un string al metodo array_unique que solo permite array

Comment: Para usar array_unique, debes enviarle un Array, ahí le estás enviado un string. Hazlo así, $variable =  [1,2,3,4,5,.......];

Answer (score 1):

Suponiendo que partes de un `string` que se compone de números separados pos comas, deberías hacer lo siguiente:

1-Convertir el string en array con la función [`explode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.explode.php) que se encarga de convertir un `string` en array dado un delimitador, en este cado la coma:

```
 $variable= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3";
 $array = explode(",",$variable);
```

2- Eliminar los valore repetidos del array con la función [`array_unique`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.array-unique.php):

```
  $array=array_unique($array);
```

3-Volver a convertir el array en `string` con la función [`implode`](http://php.net/manual/es/function.implode.php) que convierte un array en `string` separado por el delimitador dado:

```
  $variable=implode($array,",");
```

**resultado:**

> 1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9

Answer (score 1):

Convertimos el **string** a **array** con **explode** y después le pasamos el **array** obtenido a **array_unique** te dejo e ejemplo:

```
$variable= '1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3';    
$a_val = explode(',',$variable);
$a_result = array_unique($a_val);
```

La variable **$a_result** seria el **array** sin los duplicados. Si quieres pasar nuevamente el **array** a un **string** usas el método **implode** te dejo el ejemplo:

```
$varible  = implode(",",$a_result);
```

Answer (score 0):

Primero debes convertirlo en array ya que el `array_unique` espera como entrada la información en tipo de dato array

```
$variable= "1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,1,2,3,4,8,9,1,2,3";
$variable= = explode(",", $variable);
```

Así posteriormente puedes aplicar como bien mecionas el `array_unique($variable);`